# How to bind @Value with few properties?

Tags: java, spring

My application.yml contains:

```
spring: 
   someproperty: value1, value2
```

How to bind few values to one variable using @Value? Should I bind it to list or how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use spring expression language this way

```
@Value("#{'${spring.someproperty}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> properties;
```

Use List and split the comma separated values with split() method like it is done here
https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-value-import-a-list-from-properties-file/

To pass the value to the app add the properties to the startup script:
When launching the app simply add this to the startup script    -Dspring.someproperty=value1,value2 , e.g.

java -jar yourapp.jar -Dspring.someproperty=value1,value2

Comment: What should I do when I don't add a property to .yml? How to set default value?

Comment: When launching the app simply add this to the startup script -Dspring.someproperty=value1,value2

Comment: But what should I do if I want using this value as optional?

Comment: @Value("#{'${spring.property:}'.length() > 0 ? '${app.messages:}'.split(',') : null}")

Answer (score 1):

```
@Value("#{'${spring.someproperty}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> properties;
```